# Does the Information Gain algorithm favor a high-entropy attribute or a low-entropy one?

Tags: probability, statistics, information-theory, machine-learning, entropy

This might not be mutual to mathematics but it does relate to Information-Theory.

My question is:

**Does the InformationGain algorithm, in Decision-Tree machine-learning, favor a high-entropy attribute or a low-entropy one?**

The source of my confusion is in the definition of Shannon's Function:

```
                           H = -SUM(pi*log2(pi))
                               /\--this MINUS-right here!
```

If this is the case then SURELY:
                         gain = Hbefore - Hafter

Actually, means:

```
gain = Hbefore + Hafter
```

??... No, then have people just forgotten about the MINUS-sign??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus sign is NOT a subtraction. It is negative.
The reason a negative sign is there is because we are taking logarithm of probabilities.

Do it in your calculator, what is the base 2 logarithm of 0.5? That's right, it is -1. In order to make the information of a random variable that take 50% chance 0 and 50% chance 1, we need to take the negative of the logarithm to make it work.